# History table is on a seperate table after changing SYSTEM_VERSIONING to OFF

Tags: sql, sql-server

i tried this sql query :

```sql
ALTER TABLE usertable SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
```

and then i did an alter column
and finally i did

```sql
ALTER TABLE usertable SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON);
```

Then i found out that my history table became a separate table outside of usertable and new temporary history table was added to usertable

How can i fix it?

Comment: Turn it off again, then turn it on _with the explicit syntax_ to reference the other table. `(SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.PreviousHistoryTableName));`

Comment: Don't forget, as well, you need to `ALTER` *both* the temporal table *and* the history table.